# Weird HTML select tag behavior with python flask

Tags: python, html, flask

HTML with data-binding

```
 Location:<br>
  {% for item in data %}
   <select name="location">
       <option value={{ item[0] }}>{{ item[0] }}</option>
  </select>
  {% endfor %}
```

Backend

```
@app.route('/events', methods = ['post', 'get'])
def events():
    #data = ['loc1','loc2','loc3']
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM location')
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    data = [row for row in rows]
    cursor.close()
    return render_template('events.html', data = data)
```

when I render_template and pass in the data, it retrieves a list of `locations` from the database and puts it as options to select from.

This now looks like this

[image]

It's supposed to have on selection list(?) with 4 options, but there are just 4 separate selection list with on option in it.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to loop over the select options, not over the entire select block:

```
Location:<br>
  <select name="location">
   {% for item in data %}
     <option value={{ item[0] }}>{{ item[0] }}</option>
   {% endfor %}
 </select>
```